Error not found p5.js in Vercel but Vite works fine
Not showing p5,js sketches as Vercel gives an not defined error, in Vite works fine.
Also would like to go to myproject/docs and show the jsdoc documentation.
Load my project, and sketches are not shown…
https://vercel.com/ejgutierrez74s-projects/pacman2024windows
With vite works fine, but in vercel i got an error when i deploy to Vercel
Uncaught ReferenceError: p5 is not defined
    Nn https://pacman2024windows.vercel.app/assets/index-Df26wdtU.js:1776
    An https://pacman2024windows.vercel.app/assets/index-Df26wdtU.js:1
    <anonymous> https://pacman2024windows.vercel.app/assets/index-Df26wdtU.js:1776

As vite in local i want to access my index.html showing some p5.js sketches, and then if i go to myproject/docs show de index of documentation.
Structure of my project;

This is the caling of scripts in index.html in root project:
 <script type="module" src="js/libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <!--Carreguem moduls-->

    <!--Carreguem sketch-->
    <script type="module" src="/js/sketch.mjs"></script>
    <script type="module" src="/js/secondsketch.mjs"></script>

I really need help im a teacher in vocational education, and with my students we are stuck.
Thanks

Unfortunately I can't provide a detailed answer: try this vite p5.js template
